# Targeting all IE except 10

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, what is a better way to write this line

```
   if ($.browser.msie && ($.browser.version == 7 or $.browser.version == 8 or $.browser.version == 9)) {
      $("#wrapper").addClass("oldie");
   }
```

Comment: no `or` in this language, but `||`.

Comment: `$.browser.version != 10` ?

Comment: not what you're asking, but `$.browser()` has been deprecated in the latest jQuery. They are recommending use of Modernizr instead. http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Assuming you want to target all IE versions less than 10, just do `$.browser.version < 10`

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work when changing the document mode in ie10, so i can see my "oldie" styles?

Comment: @dnagirl In the latest jQuery `$.browser` was not deprecated, it was ***totally removed***.

Answer (score 5):

The best practice, is to use *conditional html comments*, like

```
<!--[if (lte IE 10)]><!--> <html class="oldie" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if (lt IE 10)]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
</html>
```

and you setup your `css classes` like

```
.someDiv {
    /* normal definitions */
}    

.oldie .someDiv {
    /* your special definition here */
}
```

---

Like @MarcelKorpel posted in the comments, IE10 will drop support for *conditional comments*. To use them anyway, you would need to include

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

this line into your markup.

Comment: I've heard that IE 10 doesn't support conditional comments anymore.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel: that would be pretty sad. Source ?

Comment: I hope IE 10 hasn't any quirks that should be addressed with conditional comments, so that `IE=EmulateIE9` isn't needed (as they say on the linked page by @Chase, one should use feature detection instead).

Comment: @MarcelKorpel: I'm just worried about lots of pages who have similar *openers* like I described in my answer, will just break in IE10 then.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. BTW, if I'm not mistaken, your solution will (try to) create *two* `html` elements in non-IE browsers, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version > 6 && $.browser.version != 10)) {
      $("#wrapper").addClass("oldie");
}
```

or

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version > 6 && $.browser.version < 10)) {
      $("#wrapper").addClass("oldie");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the `!=` operator?

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version != 10) {
    $("#wrapper").addClass("oldie");
}
```

You can also use `<` for all versions less than 10, which would be most ideal in this situation.

```
$.browser.version < 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can separate the behavior (should be in JS) from the presentation (should be in CSS). If the class is used here only for the presentation then it's better to move the version examination to your css file. There are "Conditional Comments" you can use for this purpose:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]> <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]> <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]> <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
```

For more explanations how to use them - check:
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer/comment-page-8